# App Step Forbidden error message - updating permissions group SP Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer-workflow, app-step

When I try to run a Designer 2013 workflow with an App Step, I get the following results from my log:

> 7/25/2019 4:20 PM HRO ID: i:0#.f|membership|bob@bob.gov 7/25/2019 4:20
>   PM
>   {"__metadata":{"type":"SP.User"},"LoginName":"i:0#.f|membership|bob@bob.gov"}
>   7/25/2019 4:20 PM
>   ***User Add Response Code: Forbidden

I have configured my site to allow App Steps - I can create them in my Designer workflows and publish them successfully. I know the URL I'm passing the REST call is correct because if I paste the URL directly into my browser, I get a successful result showing me the actual members of the permissions group I'm trying to update.

What should I be looking at in configurations to remedy this?

My configurations are: [image]

Comment: Please provide the screenshots of workflow steps you configured in SharePoint Designer, then we can get more information and try to reproduce and troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: The URL I'm using to make the call is:  https://<<siteUrl>>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/sitegroups(28113)/users?@target=<<siteUrl>>

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue in my SharePoint Online environment.

As a workaround, try to use Microsoft Flow to update group:

[Add The Users To The SharePoint Groups Using Microsoft Flow](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-the-users-to-the-sharepoint-groups-using-microsoft-flow/)

Comment: Unfortunately, Flow has not been deployed to our environment yet.